# Android R.java errors

Tags: android, r.java-file

I get the following error on all R.java classes:

```
Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
```

I am using eclipse, and I did clean to no avail. Nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: There must some errors in xml files ! check them properly for any errors!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Implicit+super+constructor+Object()+is+undefined+for+default+constructor.+Must+define+an+explicit+constructor&oq=Implicit+super+constructor+Object()+is+undefined+for+default+constructor.+Must+define+an+explicit+constructor&aqs=chrome.0.69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: No errors in any file

Comment: @g00dy I already did this, but was not able to fix it. That is why I posted the question here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for helping!

I just managed to fix it, by the help of one of our other programmers.

It turns out, that the .classpath file was changed (for some unknown reason) by eclipse, and the folders were not defined as source folders.

I copied his .classpath file (you can also right click on the src folder and set it to source), and it worked.

Thanks again, and I hope this might help someone else...

Comment: what do you mean by 'set it to source'?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I solved it by closing the project (right click on it in eclipse and go to close project), and then reopening it.

Answer (score 0):

try cleaning your project and rebuild it , Just a try!!